# How to fix "no such files or directory" reason?

Tags: r, install.packages

I was about to install a package. At first it displayed a warning:

> 'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/library"' is not writable.

After I tried to create a directory file using `"dir.create"`. Even after setting the working directory, it displays an error

> "no such files and directory"

This is a **windows 10 home basic**, I have a **R version of 3.6.0**

```
dir.create("c:program files/R/R-3.6.0/library/data/Rpackages")
Warning message:
In dir.create("c:program files/R/R-3.6.0/library/data/Rpackages") :
  cannot create dir 'c:program files\R\R-3.6.0\library\data\Rpackages', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Usually `Program Files` is not writable. Try to use a folder in `Documents`

Comment: How are you installing the package? Using `install.packages()`?  Are you saying you got this as a consequence of running install.packages()?  Are you using command line r or rstudio or something else?